# ASP.NET MVC: Method-Based LINQ Query of SQL Db as IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to query a database for all its record into an `IEnumerable` object. Here are the relevant codes:

**Db Context Snippet**

```
namespace WebApplicationTemp.Data
{
    public class CSVMetaDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            var connectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source=source;Initial Catalog=CSVMetaDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
        public DbSet<CSVMeta> CSVMetas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs Snippet**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddDbContext<CSVMetaDbContext>();
}
```

**Controller Snippet**

```
private readonly CSVMetaDbContext _db;

public CSVController(ICSVService csvService, CSVMetaDbContext db)
{
     _csvService = csvService;     //Can be ignored, for other applications using IService Interface
     _db = db;
}

public IActionResult Database()
{
    IEnumerable<CSVMeta> objList = _db.CSVMeta;
    return View(objList);         //Razor View not created yet due to error
}
```

The `Model` works and contain the desired data using `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`.

However, `_db.CSVMeta` contains the following error:

```
Error   CS1061  'CSVMetaDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'CSVMeta' and no accessible extension method 'CSVMeta' accepting a first argument of type 'CSVMetaDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

May I check how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a typo. In your db context class the property is named `CSVMetas` but in your controller you are calling `_db.CSVMeta`. You are missing an `s`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like typo: the collection name is `CSVMetas`:

```
IEnumerable<CSVMeta> objList = _db.CSVMetas;
```